# How to find common words or sentences or paragraphs ，from multiple paragraphs

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp

I have the following sample paragraphs:

```
para1 = "this is para one. I am cat. I am 10 years old. I like fish"
para2 = "this is para two. I am dog. my age is 12. I can swim"
para3 = "this is para three. I am cat. I am 9 years. I like rat"
para4 = "this is para four. I am rat. my age is secret. I hate cat"
para5 = "this is para five. I am dog. I am 10 years old. I like fish"
```

need results as below:

```
this is para

I am

I
```

I have tried python's **SET** data type, but the effect is not ideal.

Is there a binary executable program that allows me to construct a command line to complete my task?

Comment: Please refrain from adding random tags to your post. This is little more than spamming.

Comment: Although the question is not very well-described, it's not asking for recommendations or books, which was the argument used for closing it? It's just asking for a python code that identifies common prefixes.

Comment: Here is a one-liner solution using `os.path.commonprefix`: First `import os`, then `[os.path.commonprefix(sentences) for sentences in zip(*[p.split('.') for p in [para1,para2,para3,para4,para5]])]`. It returns the list `['this is para ', ' I am ', ' ', ' I ']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can do something like below

```
paragraph_lst = ["this is para one. I am cat. I am 10 years old. I like fish",
                     "this is para two. I am dog. my age is 12. I can swim",
                     "this is para three. I am cat. I am 9 years. I like rat",
                     "this is para four. I am rat. my age is secret. I hate cat",
                     "this is para five. I am dog. I am 10 years old. I like fish"]
    
    word_combinations = set()
    
    
    def get_combinations(line1, line2, first=0, last=1, prvs_wrd=""):
        line_lst = line1.split(" ")
        if last > len(line_lst):
            return
        chk_list = line_lst[first:last]
        wrd = " ".join(str(x) for x in chk_list)
        if wrd in line2:
            prvs_wrd = wrd
            get_combinations(line1, line2, first, last + 1, prvs_wrd)
        else:
            word_combinations.add(prvs_wrd)
            get_combinations(line1, line2, last, last + 1, prvs_wrd)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for n, line in enumerate(paragraph_lst):
            if n + 1 < len(paragraph_lst):
                str1 = paragraph_lst[n]
                str2 = paragraph_lst[n + 1]
                get_combinations(str1, str2)
        print(word_combinations)
```

thus the set word_combinations will gives the result below

```
{'I', 'I am', 'is', 'this is para'}
```

Comment: I found a similar algorithm in Leetcode, but your algorithm is clearer and easier to understand!! https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-duplicate-substring/